# Azure Application Gateway + WAF: turn down on CRON

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

### Objective

I'm going to use Azure Application Gateway. I'm expecting it would be triggered few times a day (integration with external tools), so I'm expecting it to be very cheap. Though from [pricing details](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-application-firewall/) I have to use Medium, because only Medium supports WAF.

### Issue

I can't find a good way to start and stop App Gateway & WAF based on CRON. Because of that instead of paying < 1$ / month I have to pay 100$/month for the environment.

### Question

*What is the good way to start/stop App Gateway + WAF based on CRON and pay on per-minute basis as promised?*

Answer (score 0):

If you know when you will receive the calls (like a set time range each day) you could use Azure Functions with a timer job and a Managed Identity to spin up and then spin down an App Gateway.   Azure Functions supports PowerShell so all the automation could be down in that pattern.

Generally speaking, most customers do not treat App Gateways with WAF as dynamic scale to zero resources.  Typically they are tied to DNS entries (fqdn) and therefore need to be up most of the time.